# Strang, Introduction to Linear Algebra Strang (2016 5th edition), problem 2.4.32, page 82.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling to solve question 33:

> 32 (*Very important*) Suppose you solve $Ax=b$ for three different right sides b:
>
> $Ax_1= (1,0,0)$
>
> $Ax_2 = (0,1,0)$
>
> $Ax_3 = (0,0,1)$
>
> If the three solutions $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the columns of a matrix X, what is A times X?

> 33. If the three solutions in Question 32 are $x_1 = (1, 1, 1), x_2= (0, 1, 1), x_3 = (0,0,1)$, solve $Ax = b$ when $b = (3,5,8)$. Challenge problem: What is $A$?

In the solutions manual I see that $x = 3x_1 + 5x_2 + 8x_3 = (3,8,16)$.

I am struggling to see intuition behind this. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}(3,5,8)&=3(1,0,0)+5(0,1,0)+8(0,0,1)\\&=3A(1,1,1)+5A(0,1,1)+8A(0,0,1)\\&=A\bigl(3(1,1,1)+5(0,1,1)+8(0,0,1)\bigr)\\&=A(3,8,16).\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We can say that $A^{-1}$ exists (since $A$ takes a basis to a basis),and we know what it does to the standard basis.

Now $(3,5,8)=3e_1+5e_2+8e_3$.  Using linearity we get $x=A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}b=A^{-1}(3,5,8)=3A^{-1}e_1+5A^{-1}e_2+8A^{-1}e_3=3(1,1,1)+5(0,1,1)+8(0,0,1)=(3,8,16)$ is the unique solution.

Comment: Thanks but what do the 's signify? I have not seen this convention.

Comment: $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$.  This is the standard basis.

Comment: Thank you it matches the answer above i just wanted to be sure.